# Свет в 2d играх

Tags: c++, opengl, opengles

Балуюсь созданием своего движка и игр под него и встал такой вопрос: как правильно сделать осещение? Методом умозаключений, проб и ошибок, решил сделать следующим образом:

1) Выделить для источников света `n` `uniform` размером в 3 `float`. В каждом таком векторе хранятся: координаты (первые два значения) и мощность источника света.

2) Во фрагментном шейдере для каждого пикселя на экране выщитывается расстояние до каждого источника света и соответственный коэффициент освещенности (1 - расстояние / мощность).

3) Коэффициент освещёности умножается на `r`, `g` & `b` и получаем выходной цвет.

Данный способ работает, но у него, конечно, есть очевидные недостатки: строго ограниченное количество источников света (ограниченное как заранее установленных в шэйдеры юниформ, так и общим количеством юниформ - 128, если не ошибаюсь) и большой объем рассчетов. Как сделать освещение более эффективно?

Comment: Свет без теней, правильно? Типа такого: http://vodacek.zvb.cz/archiv/stranky/1260d75c94888dad7e26439b700576e6.png ?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да. Думал еще об этом и появилась новая идея: считать свет первым и записывать в буфер (расчитывать в вершинном шейдере размеры квадратов и потом интерполировать), а после - все текстуры. Это устранит ограничения на количество источников света и значительно ускорит процесс.

Comment: правда я пока не понимаю как в этом случае производить конечный рассчет света - смешение не то, нужно умножение.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это делается так:

- Создаете отдельную текстуру, размером с экран. И фреймбуфер для нее.
- В начале каждого кадра заполняете ее черным.
- Переключаетесь на additive blending (`glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE)`).
- Рисуете на нее белые круги с размыленными краями и черным фоном (то есть либо квадраты с текстурой, либо квадраты с хитрым шейдером) с центрами в источниках света.
  (За счет additive blending этот черный фон *не будет* мешать соседним источникам света.)
- Отключаете этот фреймбуфер и рисуете остальную графику как обычно.
- Потом поверх всего рисуете ту текстуру освещения, с режимом смешивания (`glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_SRC_COLOR)`). По сути это умножение картинки на содержимое текстуры.
- Все, получаете красивую картинку с освещением.

При таком подходе можно источники освещения плодить сотнями, вешая их на все подряд, без просадки FPS.

---

Возможны разные вариации:

- Можно финальное смешивание проводить в отдельном шейдере.
- Можно использовать цветное освещение, рисуя круги цветными.
- Можно объединять свет от разных источников с помощью разных необычных функций смешивания.

Comment: отлично, примерно то же, что и я себе представлял. Правда я не был не в курсе, что можно рисовать в отдельный буфер и потом их объеденять. Не подскажете как это происходит, ну или ссылку, хотя бы?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Про рисование в отдельный буфер - нужно копать в сторону framebuffer'ов (кратко - это такие штуки, к которым можно цеплять текстуры, чтобы в эти текстуры потом рисовать). А чтобы потом объединить - просто рисуете прямоугольник с полученной текстурой на нем на экран.

Comment: ага, спасибо, помогли)